# Error creating virtual host in wamp

Tags: wamp, virtualhost

Recently I had to wipe my Windows 10 out and re-install it. Now wamp's create virtual host is broken.

I am using latest WAMP server, and while creating virtual host through wamp functionality `http://localhost/add_vhost.php?lang=english` I am getting following error.

> Warning: fopen(C:\WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc/hosts): failed to open
>   stream: Resource temporarily unavailable in C:\wamp\www\add_vhost.php
>   on line 442

Seems like I can't edit hosts file. I tried manually editing it in notepad++ with administrative privileges but it didn't work.

**Anyway to make the hosts file accessible and editable by wamp ?**

Comment: Did you install WAMPServer using "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Are you launching WAMPServer using "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Do you have some firewall that is stopping access to the hosts file. Some do try and protect it and have to be set NOT to deny access to the hosts file, either temporarily (next 15 mins) or set to allow certain programs to access it

Comment: @RiggsFolly It was the firewall, Thanks :)